# I need to generate a Barcode with every item created

Tags: workflow, newform, barcodes

I'm new to SharePoint, and I need to auto generate a barcode containing a specific value from a lookup column to then print the item details and the barcode with a specific Font.. any help would be appreciated.

I know that SharePoint had a feature to create a barcode and it has been disabled, but I don't need a random barcode number from a specific range, I need it to also include the value from the lookup column

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/barcode-generation-in-sharepoint